# Post the image created by createObjectURL()

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I want to read the image generated and to send to server.

```
<img id="image" src="blob:null/31070c0f-23c0-44b0-945f-57ed1e623350">
```

This code generated the image.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

        var img = document.getElementById('image');
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response); // this one created the image.
```

I want to read the data to post it. I tried to attach it to a file (not work), tried to read the binary from image (not work- the image is local blob), I tried to set the src of image to file (not work)

```
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http://www.cognation.net/profile');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();  

<img id="image" />
```

This is how the image is rendered. I want to send it to server.
[image: This is how the image is rendered]

I tried some ways, couldn't answer.

Answer (score 1):

To send your image through POST send the blob directly thanks to the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)
To convert a blob to a dataURI, use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)
But in your case the FormData approach should be prefered.

Just a note about using a canvas : this will decode the image, then reencode it with a different algorithm. The output won't be the same image.

Comment: Right now I am having that problem. trying to correct it,dataurl produces blank image.

Comment: Not able to produce the image from canvas, it is blank. can you show me file reader to send the image from img tag.

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan, take the `blob` received by the xhr (probably still in `xhr.response` but safer to save it in a variable available in the same scope as your upload function). Then, since what you want is to upload this image, use `var form = new FormData(); form.append('file', blob, 'filename.ext')` then create a POST xhr and just call `postXHR.send(form)`. If you need to store it as a dataURI, then do the conversion server-side.

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan For how to use FileReader, it seems you were able to read through MDN according to your last answer's edit

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){               

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var dataURL = reader.result;
            $("#image").attr("src", dataURL);

            alert($("#ImageTwo").attr("src"));
        }

        var read =   reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);

    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http://www.cognation.net/profile');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```